# Jquery UI Button function execute on popup dialog open

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my Code, after popup dialog box open need to click the button the function given should work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var box = $('#openbox').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 100,
                height: 200,
                title: 'hi',
                modal: true
            });
            $('#open-box').click(function () {
                getbtn = $('#openbox').dialog({
                    buttons: {
                        "view": sayhi()
                    }
                });
                getbtn.dialog("open");
            });
            function sayhi() {
                alert("hi..");
            }
        });
```

But problem is while opening popup dialog box the **function sayhi()** is working. not showing any name in button and button click in popup box not working. how to do this?

Comment: may be call like `"view":function(){sayhi();}` ?

Comment: its working now thanks @NullPoiиteя

Comment: @NullPoiиteя sure its working and thanks for support i am waiting to click this as answer...!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not call function like that because

```
"view"://here you have  object which have method view
```

To call that try

```
getbtn.button.view
```

and to call directory just use this

```
"view": sayhi();
```